# Python string concatenation slow when using join

Tags: python, string, concatenation, processing-efficiency

I have the following code that should concatenate all the text files in a directory into one file. Even though I am using join for the string concatenation the string concatenation just gets slower and slower (60 seconds instead of 3 seconds after 14000 files). What am I doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.now()

directory_in_str = "E:\\Downloads\\WikipediaAF\\Extracted\\"
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

c = 1
af = ''
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    c = c + 1
    if c % 1000 == 0:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        print('Time now: ' + str(t2 - t1))
        print(str(c) + ' out of 67062')
    #    break
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    with open(os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename), encoding="utf8") as f_in:
        af = ''.join([af, '== ', filename, ' ==\n', f_in.read().replace(" 'n ", " ’n ")])
```

Comment: Calling `join` in a loop isn't any better than calling `+` in a loop. The idea is that you gather up *all* the strings you're going to join and join them in *one call* instead of calling `join` over and over again.

Comment: I gather them in a loop into a list?

Comment: `data = set();with open(os.path.join(whatever, whatever)) as file:;for line in file.readlines():;data.add(line.strip());return list(data)` something like that will give you a list of unique elements in the file

Comment: Why would I want to for line (and produce even more strings to concatenate) when I can just read the whole file at once?

Comment: Is deque faster than a list to append to and can I use deque in the join?

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from datetime import datetime
from collections import deque

t1 = datetime.now()

directory_in_str = "E:\\Downloads\\WikipediaAF\\Extracted\\"
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

c = 1
af = deque()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    c = c + 1
    if c % 1000 == 0:
        t2 = datetime.now()
        print('Time now: ' + str(t2 - t1))
        print(str(c) + ' out of 67062')
    #    break
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    with open(os.path.join(directory_in_str, filename), encoding="utf8") as f_in:
        af.append('== ')
        af.append(filename)
        af.append(' ==\n')
        af.append(f_in.read().replace(" 'n ", " ’n "))

t2 = datetime.now()
print('After read af: ' + str(t2 - t1))

af = ''.join(af)

t2 = datetime.now()
print('After join af: ' + str(t2 - t1))

with open(os.path.join(directory_in_str, 'af_out2.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    f_out.write(af)
```